# C# Form in IronPython's thread. Which thread it runs on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, ironpython

I'm creating an IronPython application that uses Windows Form as a user interface. The form is built in a Dll and I create a separate thread to run this form using static methods of Application class. This way the form remains user-responsive while python script performs calculations and updates form's controls.

```
clr.AddReference('MyDialogs');
from MyDialogs import UserRuntimeDialog;
from System.Windows.Forms import Application;
from System.Threading import *;

def threadjob():
    global form;
    Application.Run(form);

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
form = UserRuntimeDialog();
t = Thread(ThreadStart(threadjob));
t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
t.IsBackground = True;
t.Start();
```

According to .Net documentation only the thread that created a control can access and/or modify its contents. This fact allows me to change form's properties from IronPython, e.g. set progress bar value and so on because that's the thread in which the form has been created. But if I read managed thread id *inside* the form (e.g. by displaying it in the form) I get value different from main Python's thread.
So my questions are:

1. Why does form *see* different thread id?
2. Is it a safe design of form-Python interaction?